# Set bs64 string for pdf into PdfMake js-plugin

Tags: javascript, pdfmake

On client side I have bs64 string for all PDF files in memory. 
Can I set bs64 string into pdfMake js-plugin ? Because I must put a lot of files in ONE BIG file.
Something like this:

```
var docDefinition = {
  content: [
    {
      pdf: 'data:pdf/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...'
    }
};
pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download('Name.pdf');
```

Or pdfMake-js have this method only for images?

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: it is for images only I think, you need to convert images to `dataURL`